# How can I improve the question about improving an office environment and can it be re-opened?

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

This is the question:
https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/49755/suggestions-for-improving-an-office-environment

It is closed too quickly and it is down-voted after two very good answers. It can be interpreted as too broad but I tried to ask a good subjective question with right amount of information. It attracted two detailed and good answers.

For example, this question is too broad also to me but it is a good subjective question:
[How to improve non-verbal communication in the workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1397/how-to-improve-non-verbal-communication-in-the-workplace)

or maybe this one:
[Suggestions for building relationships as a remote office worker?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/9590/suggestions-for-building-relationships-as-a-remote-office-worker)

What is the limit of "too-broad" in this platform and how can I improve my question for a possible re-open?

Note: I also read help section but being too specific about your company is off-topic as well. Additionally, I wanted to hear examples from people and I wanted them to share their experiences.

Comment: I was one of the close-voters, and I have now voted to reopen the edited question.

Answer (score 5):

It's too broad because it doesn't give any parameters.  What a 10-person company with a capital budget of $5000 can do is very different from what, say, Facebook can do.  Knowing *something* about the parameters -- how much space you have to work with, how many people, what size budget, what behaviors you're trying to facilitate, other design considerations (like "some people are noise-averse") -- will move it from a broad theoretical *discussion* a question about *your problem*.  We're best-suited to solving problems, not having philosophical discussions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I don't see how it is a philosophical discussion and there were already parameters in the question. I admit it is broad but many questions are broad here and everyone comes up with opinions/suggestions. I think it has an acceptable level of broadness. For example, how are the other questions I mentioned not too broad? There is also good subjective question factor here. But anyway, I will follow your suggestion and add more parameters.

Comment: Added more parameters now. Please let me know if I can improve further. Thanks and +1 :)

Comment: Thanks; that's much better.  In general, I think it's better if questions are more specific and answers *expend* on that to demonstrate general principles.  That gets the asker a good answer while teaching all readers ways to look at the problem (so if their specific case is a little different they can still use it).  I haven't checked the other questions you referenced yet -- at work now and just driving by, so to speak, but I wanted to help out with what I could.  I support reopening the edited question.